# Setting scrollView.delegate to scrollView and not UITableView

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiscrollview

I've set up a scrollView inside my custom cell. Inside my tableViewController I've used...

```
UIScrollViewDelegate
```

...Which fill delegate when the "scrollView" has moved. Though, I only want it to react when the image scroll view is moved.

It currently reacts to both, when the tablView scrolls and image scrollview scrolls.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    //other irrelevant cell setup....

    scrollView = cell.imageScrollView
    scrollView.pagingEnabled = true
    scrollView.scrollEnabled = true        
    scrollView.delegate = self
    scrollView.tag = indexPath.row
}

func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    var pageWidth = scrollView.frame.size.width
    var newPage = floor((scrollView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1
    //prints: 0.0 ,  while tableView scrolls
    //also, prints newPage when scrollView is moved

    print(newPage)
}
```

I've tried to use sender but didn't know who to properly incorporate it. Any ideas? It seems that....

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)sender{}
```

... no longer exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try use `isMemberOfClass()`，like this:

```
if sender.isMemberOfClass(UITableView) {
     // your logic
}
else sender.isMemberOfClass(UIScrollView)
{
     // your logic    
}
```